# htaccess rewrite only the part after .tld

Tags: .htaccess, rewrite, regex

I have the following htaccess rule which does what I want:
it rewrite any request to index.php. However, can i make this independent of the `https://subsub.sub` part?

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subsub.sub.domain.example/index.php [L]
```

I would like to have something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*\.domain\.example)$ $1/index.php [L]
```

or even something like:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php" [L]
```

(Edit: where I expect `HTTP_HOST` to be `https://subsub.sub.domain.example`)

However, this does not work.
Both ideas result in 500 errors.

Edit: Apache error log:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
```

However, I can't set LogLevel in an htaccess file. How can I debug this on shared hosting in an efficient way?

Comment: Rather than trying to pose your question as a series of (invalid) code samples (which may convey the wrong meaning anyway) you should state the question in natural language with examples that clearly show the URLs you are wanting to redirect from/to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://subsub.sub.domain.example/index.php [L]
> ```

This will result in an external 302 (temporary) redirect, not a "rewrite", as you've stated. The implied *redirect* occurs because of the absolute URL (scheme + hostname) in the substitution.

However, by itself this would seemingly cause a redirect-loop<sup>***1**</sup>, so presumably you have some preceding *conditions* (ie. `RewriteCond` directives) to prevent this?

<sup>(***1** Unless you are redirecting to an entirely different filesystem? Although that is not suggested in your question.)</sup>

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*\.domain\.example)$ $1/index.php [L]
> ```

You can't match the hostname with the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches the URL-path only. To match the requested hostname you need a `RewriteCond` directive that checks against the `HTTP_HOST` server variable.

> ```
> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php" [L]
> ```

The `HTTP_HOST` server variable contains the hostname only (ie. the value of the `Host` HTTP request header, hence the name `HTTP_HOST`). In other words, `HTTP_HOST` would contain `subsub.sub.domain.example` in your example. So, your directive is missing the scheme `https://` that you would need to manually prefix to the substitution string, eg. `"https://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.php"`. Without the *scheme*, it will be seen as a relative URL and without the `R` (`redirect`) flag, an "internal redirect" (otherwise known as a "rewrite") is triggered - hence the reported error.

To *externally redirect* all requests to `/index.php` on the same host/domain when requesting a hostname of form `*.domain.example` (where `*` is any subdomain) then you would need to do something like the following:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} \.domain\.example$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php [R,L]
```

No need to specify the hostname in the substitution at all if you simply want to redirect to the *same* hostname on the request. (This is assuming `UseCanonicalName On` is not set in the server config - which is not the default.)

No need for the capturing/verbose `^(.*)$` regex, which is less efficient. You are simply matching everything and not using this in the *substitution*. Alternatively use a pattern like `.?` to match *anything* instead.

And as mentioned at the start of my answer, this does assume you already have other conditions that prevent a redirect-loop.